# Using Regex to Parse Latex in Markdown

Tags: regex, parsing, visual-studio-code, regex-greedy

In markdown file: I am hoping to find `{\display` with its matching `}` in VS Code (doesn't support look behind). In the following text:

```
Type-2  Context-free    Non-deterministic pushdown automaton    {\displaystyle A\rightarrow \gamma } A \rightarrow \gamma

Type-3  Regular Finite state automaton  {\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}} {\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}} and {\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}B} {\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}B}
```

I hope to identify:

`{\displaystyle A\rightarrow \gamma }
{\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}}
{\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}}
{\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}B}
{\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}B}`

I think the regex should start with this `{\` and be greedy for `}` but should not include `{\` after the matching `}`.

I tried `(\{\\.*\})` but this doesn't identify all the cases.

Summary: The answer will be most general if it stops at last `}` before the next occurrence of `{\display` and between these two there can be any character.

Comment: Please explain why voted for close?

Comment: this should work for your given examples: `{\\display.+?}+(\w})?`

Comment: @Deathshadow Thanks! It would be great if you could convert it into an answer and explain if possible! :)

Answer (score 1):

With your given Example this should work: `{\\display.+?}+(\w})?`

Explanation:

`{\\display` -> looks if it begins with `{` followed by a `\` and by the word `display`

`.+?}+` -> matches any character non greedy until the first `}` of which there can be multiple

`(\w})` -> matches any word character with a `}` after it (this part is for the last                 two character of this example you gave: `{\displaystyle A\rightarrow {\text{a}}B}` so it would match `B}`

Hope this helped!

Comment: Your answer works in this case perfectly! But is it possible to have a more general Regex, because `\w` character class fails if we have some other character. The ultimate goal is to match the text between matching curly braces of latex command.

Comment: Example `{\\display.+?}+(\w*})*` can find `{\displaystyle \alpha  \rightarrow \beta }dsss}sdssdd}`. But not `{\displaystyle \alpha  \rightarrow \beta }ds + ss}sdssdd}`

Comment: The answer will be most general if it stops at last } before the next occurrence of {\display and between these two there can be any character.

Comment: @Nikhil that is true but then the last one won't be matched because there is not a following {\display

Comment: So it should stop at last `}` but before `{\display|\n`